# EF Can't update one-to-zero or one relationship fields, but updates the rest

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

Am trying to make an update on the database with one-to-one relationship models, but only the `Student` **model** fields are the only ones working. How can I make the rest update too?

This is my **Repository** method for updating :

```
 public void Edit(Student student)
        {
            var existingStudent = _context.Students
                .Include(e => e.Education)
                .Include(s => s.Siblings)
                .Include(p => p.Parents)
                .Include(g => g.Guardian)
                .Single(s => s.Id == student.Id);

            if (existingStudent != null)
            {
                // do some updating.
                _context.Attach(existingStudent);
                _context.Entry(existingStudent).CurrentValues.SetValues(student);
                _context.Entry(existingStudent).State = EntityState.Modified;
                _context.SaveChanges();

            }


        }
```

Then, this is my `Student` **model** class :

```
public class Student
    {
        [Key]
        public long Id { get; set; }
        [Display(Name="First Name")]
        public string FirstName { get; set; }
        [Display(Name="Middle Name")]
        public string MiddleName { get; set; }
        [Display(Name="Last Name")]
        public string LastName { get; set; }
        [Display(Name="Nationality")]
        public string Nationality { get; set; }
        [Display(Name="Gender")]
        public string Gender { get; set; }
        [Display(Name="Religion")]
        public string Religion { get; set; }
        [Display(Name="Medical Condition")]
        public string MedicalCondition { get; set; }
        [Display(Name="Deceased")]
        public string Deceased { get; set; }
        [Display(Name="Home Address")]
        public string HomeAddress { get; set; }
        [Display(Name="Country Of Residence")]
        public string CountryOfResidence { get; set; }
        [Display(Name="City")]
        public string City { get; set; }
        [Display(Name="Date Of Birth")]
        public DateTime DateOfBirth { get; set; }
        public int Age { get; set; }
        public virtual Parents Parents { get; set; }
        public virtual Education Education { get; set; }
        public virtual Guardian Guardian { get; set; }
        public virtual Siblings Siblings { get; set; }
    }
```

Then one of the one-to-one relationship classes is as below :

```
public class Siblings
    {
        public long Id { get; set; }
        [Display(Name="Number of Brothers")]
        public int NumberOfBrothers { get; set; }
        [Display(Name="Number of Sisters")]
        public int NumberOfSisters { get; set; }

        public Student Student { get; set; }

        public  long? StudentId { get; set; }
    }
```

The rest of the related model classes `Parents`, `Education`, `Guardian` are the same as `Siblings`.

How can I be able to ensure that the update cuts across all the fields. Thanks.

**EDIT**

This is what I have in `OnModelCreating()` :

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder builder)
        {
            base.OnModelCreating(builder);

            builder.Entity<Student>()
                .HasOne(e => e.Education)
                .WithOne(s => s.Student)
                ;


            builder.Entity<Student>()
                .HasOne(g => g.Guardian)
                .WithOne(s => s.Student);

            builder.Entity<Student>()
                .HasOne(p => p.Parents)
                .WithOne(s => s.Student);

            builder.Entity<Student>()
                .HasOne(s => s.Siblings)
                .WithOne(s => s.Student);


            builder.Entity<Education>()
                .HasOne(s => s.Student)
                .WithOne(e => e.Education);
            builder.Entity<Guardian>()
                .HasOne(s => s.Student)
                .WithOne(g => g.Guardian);

            builder.Entity<Parents>()
                .HasOne(s => s.Student)
                .WithOne(p => p.Parents);

            builder.Entity<Siblings>()
                .HasOne(s => s.Student)
                .WithOne(p => p.Siblings);


}
```

Comment: EF Core or EF .NET Framework?

Comment: EF .NET Framewrok

Comment: What's your `OnModelCreating` (Fluent API config) look like?

Comment: @AdamVincent, I have included the `OnModelCreating()` in the question, please check it out.

Answer (score 3):

I suggest you try two ways below:

1. Modify the navigation property

   ```
   _context.Entry(existingStudent).CurrentValues.SetValues(student);
   _context.Entry(existingStudent).State = EntityState.Modified;
   _context.Entry(existingStudent.Siblings).CurrentValues.SetValues(student.Siblings);
   _context.Entry(existingStudent.Siblings).State = EntityState.Modified;
   ```
2. Update with `_context.Update`

   ```
   var existingStudent = _context.Student
       .Include(s => s.Siblings)
       .AsNoTracking()
       .Single(s => s.Id == 4);

   if (existingStudent != null)
   {
       existingStudent = student;
       _context.Update(existingStudent);
       _context.SaveChanges();
   }
   ```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if you have any Fluent configuration, but if you don't,

As seen [in this link](https://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/code-first/configure-one-to-one-relationship-in-code-first.aspx)

You need to configure the relationship using the Fluent API.

Without knowing your complete requirement, I'm going to take a stab in the dark that this is *probably* what you're looking for.

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    modelBuilder.Entity<Student>()
                .HasOptional(s => s.Siblings) // Mark Siblings property optional in Student entity
                .WithRequired(ad => ad.Student); // mark Student property as required in Siblings entity. Cannot save Siblings without Student
}
```

## EDIT

If `HasOptional` and `WithRequired` are giving you red squiggles, then you're most likely using EF CORE and not EF 6, unless you have a major problem elsewhere.

Addressing your current problem, in your Fluent configuration (`OnModelCreating()`)

First, what you are looking for is not how to configure one-to-one relationships.  Your intending to configure one-to-zero or one relationships.

Second, given the following configuration

```
builder.Entity<Student>()
    .HasOne(s => s.Siblings)
    .WithOne(s => s.Student);
```

This means: `Entity<Student>` requires one `Sibling`, and `Entity<Sibling>` requires one `Student` So your configuration is not doing what you want it to do.

Last, since EF Core has some pretty smart conventions, it will actually figure out that your `nullable` foreign key means it's optional, and will create your (0->0..1) relationship for you with out any config.

The Solution, simply remove all fluent config from your `OnModelCreating()` and let EF do it's job.  And don't forget to `update-database`.

Comment: Thanks for the response but , It seems `HasOptional` and `WithRequired` cannot be resolved

Comment: So, then you're using EF Core?

Comment: Hey adam, maybe this confused me but yeah am using EF core